# Spring Boot : JAXBElement null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am totally new to Junit 5 and Mockito framework. Now I am trying to implement JUnit test cases for the function. Can someone help in Mocking, because the below test implementation throws a NullPointerException at the specified line.

```
Class XYZ{

       @Autowired
       private SoapCall soapCall;

       public void validate(){
 
                 //code....

            JAXBElement <SubDTO> jax = (JAXBElement <Sub_DTO>) soapCall.callSoapService(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5);
 
            SubDTO  response = jax.getValue();  // Getting null pointer exception while Unit testing at this line   

        }
}
```

**Unit Testing**

```
Class TestValid{

   @Mock
   SoapCall soapCall;

   @InjectMocks
   XYZ xyzzy;

   @BeforeEach
   void setUp(){
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void test1(){
        SubDTO dto= new SubDTO("a","b","c");

        JAXBElement<SubDTO> jax = new JAXBElement <> (any(), any(), any());

        jax.setValue(dto)            

   Mockito.when(soapCall.callSoapService(any(),any(),any(),anyInt(),anyInt())).thenReturn( jax );

        Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(()->xyz.validate());
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident you get should get IllegalArgumentExeption at an earlier point: `new JAXBElement <> (any(), any(), any())`. Please show us the stack trace. See https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-spec/blob/b25f7217b22d0ff17e6f160f28b1521399fc42f6/jaxb-api/src/main/java/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.java#L125

Answer (score 1):

This line looks odd to me:

```java
        JAXBElement<SubDTO> jax = new JAXBElement <> (any(), any(), any());
```

`any()` is a matcher and is only used when setting up mocking or during verification.  It always returns `null`.

Basically, you are writing code that will do the same as this:

```java
        JAXBElement<SubDTO> jax = new JAXBElement <> (null, null, null);
```

Instead of passing in `null` values, pass in a `QName`, a class and an instance of that class as the arguments to the `JAXBElement` constructor.

However, I don't get a `NullPointerException` when I attempt to run your code.  I get an `IllegalArgumentException` at the line above, complaining about the `null` values.